# input text and button same height top align

Tags: html, css

I have 2 button input and a text input in between them. As you can see on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jq9frv1L/1/) text input is not top aligned with the button. How can I align top align both text and buttons?

```css
.incriDecriButton {
  border:1px solid #cdcdcd;
  width:16px;
  height:24px;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
  border-radius:1px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:16px;
  padding:0px;margin:0px;
}
.inputText-Quantity {
  border:1px solid #cdcdcd;
  height:22px;
  width:30px;
  font-size:10px;
  margin-top:-5px !important;
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<input type='button' class='incriDecriButton' value='-' /><input type='text' class='inputText-Quantity' maxlength='4' /><input type='button' class='incriDecriButton' value='+' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed `height`, added `display` and `vertical-align`:

```css
.incriDecriButton {
  border:1px solid #cdcdcd;
  width:16px;
  height:24px;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
  border-radius:1px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:16px;
  padding:0px;margin:0px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}
.inputText-Quantity {
  border:1px solid #cdcdcd;
  height:20px;
  width:30px;
  font-size:10px;
  margin-top:-5px !important;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type='button' class='incriDecriButton' value='-' /><input type='text' class='inputText-Quantity' maxlength='4' /><input type='button' class='incriDecriButton' value='+' />
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
[codepen](http://codepen.io/venumadhavdiv/pen/GZqgaV)

```
<input type='button' class='incriDecriButton' value='-' /><input type='text' class='inputText-Quantity' maxlength='4' /><input type='button' class='incriDecriButton' value='+' />


.incriDecriButton {
    border:1px solid #cdcdcd;
    width:16px;
    height:24px;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    border-radius:1px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:16px;
    padding:0px;margin:0px;
}
.inputText-Quantity {
    border:1px solid #cdcdcd;
    height:20px;
    width:30px;
    font-size:10px;
    margin-top: -5px !important;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;


}
```

Comment: What's the use when I have already answered it perfectly to the point and you have just blatantly copied the same code and ... What are you trying to prove? `:)`

Comment: I believe it is better for you to delete it rather than being a decoy. Man! Be original!

Comment: @Praveen Kumar why do you think I copied your code? is it because of using display inline-block property? are you holding trademark for that? I am just trying to say that you can't blame others unnecessarily that they copied your code. In this case, I didn't copy your code. It is completely my work. I suggest you to take your words back and show respect to other users. :)

Comment: Venu, `20px` height, and `inline-block`, that's the fix. Man, if you didn't copy, well and good. Then I am really sorry and take back my words. `:(`

Comment: @PraveenKumar it's ok buddy.:)